# Php getting unique distinct output

Tags: php, algorithm

Hi i have issues here with this algorithm.

```
<?php
function get_all_substrings($input){
$subs = array();
$length = strlen($input);
for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++){
    for($j=$i; $j<$length; $j++){
        $subs[] = substr($input, $i, ($j - $i) + 1);    
    }   
}   
return $subs;
}

$subs = get_all_substrings("kikilala");
print_r($subs);

?>
```

It should return me 30 unique results as follow

```
 'a', 'al', 'ala', 'i', 'ik', 'iki', 'ikil', 'ikila', 'ikilal', 'ikilala', 'il', 'ila', 'ilal', 'ilala', 'k', 'ki', 'kik', 'kiki', 'kikil', 'kikila', 'kikilal', 'kikilala', 'kil', 'kila', 'kilal', 'kilala', 'l', 'la', 'lal', 'lala'
```

But i am getting

```
Array ( [0] => k [1] => ki [2] => kik [3] => kiki [4] => kikil [5] => kikila [6] => kikilal [7] => kikilala [8] => i [9] => ik [10] => iki [11] => ikil [12] => ikila [13] => ikilal [14] => ikilala [15] => k [16] => ki [17] => kil [18] => kila [19] => kilal [20] => kilala [21] => i [22] => il [23] => ila [24] => ilal [25] => ilala [26] => l [27] => la [28] => lal [29] => lala [30] => a [31] => al [32] => ala [33] => l [34] => la [35] => a )
```

Where am i wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Thats because some substrings are duplicate. For example `ki`, `al`, `la` etc. To fix this just run `array_unique`.

```
$subs = array_unique(get_all_substrings("kikilala"));
```

**Note:** The array_unique will not reset the indexes. So *calculating-array-length-by-observing-the-last-index* trick will not work here. To reset the indices use `array_values`.

```
$subs = array_values(array_unique(get_all_substrings("kikilala")));
```

If you want it sorted

```
$subs = array_unique(get_all_substrings("kikilala"));
sort($subs);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want unique then you'll need to check whether or not the subs array already contains the entry you're about to add.

For example it's going to add several 'k','i','l', and 'a' characters. So when it comes time to adding a new entry you'll need to search the subs array and only add it if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Because some tokens are duplicated. Try [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) your $subs:

```
$subs = array_unique($subs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add these lines to your code..

```
sort($subs);
$subs = array_unique($subs);
```

See your desired output at **[Codepad](http://codepad.org/1gl9YTnC)**.

Comment: You should answer WHY, not the FIX.

Comment: WHY can be easily understood with this FIX.

Answer (score 0):

you are having multiple issues with loops, if I assume that your 1st/outer loop is for word length and 2nd/inner loop is for word location then here are the mistakes

1. why starting with $i=0, it is useless should be 1
2. if you want full word included in sub-strings then outer/length loop must include full length i.e $i<=$length;
3. why inner/location loop starting from $j=$i it should be 0
4. in substr location argument should be $j and length argument should be $i

I also have added one extra condition to filter out uncompleted selection in substr which cause duplicate. final code is here

```
    function get_all_substrings($input) {
      $subs = array();
      $length = strlen($input);
      for ($i=1; $i<=$length; $i++) {
        for ($j=0; $j<$length; $j++) {
          if ($length >= ($i + $j)) {
            $subs[] = substr($input, $j, $i);
          }
        }   
      }   
      return $subs;
    }

    $subs = get_all_substrings("kikilala");
    print_r($subs);
```

Comment: After you have complete list of sub-strings, you are free to sort or filter out duplicates from the array.

Answer (score -1):

1 - String length decrease by 1 for (last position)

2 - first loop decreas by 1 every time

Try:

```
<?php
function get_all_substrings($input){
    $subs = array();
    $length = strlen($input)-1; //change this line
    for($i=$length; $i>=0; $i--){ //and change this line
        for($j=$i; $j<$length; $j++){
            $subs[] = substr($input, $i, ($j - $i) + 1);    
        }   
    }   
    return $subs;
}

$subs = get_all_substrings("kikilala");
print_r($subs);

?>
```

Comment: **-1** How does this solves the problem? did you even try it?